# I need to remove 100mV of ripple out of my 12Vdc source. What size and type capacitor do I need?

Tags: filter

I am building a very inexpensive power monitor. I need a clean 12Vdc power source for the current transducers. I currently have 100mV of ripple on the 12Vdc source i am using which is causing issues related to the output signal from the CTs. I not an electrical engineer but more of a glorified technician. I am thinking a capacitor between the +12Vdc and GND will do the trick but do not know what size or type capacitor I need.

Comment: What is your load impedance?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 100mV (however you're measuring it) of high frequency ripple from a switching power supply you may be better off adding a regulator or LDO. Most regulators will let more high frequency stuff through than low frequency, so be sure to compare the regulation with an actual input from the power supply.

For example, the ubiquitous LM317 could be used to make (say) a 10V supply, but the ripple regulation is only specified at 120Hz (-65dB typical).

You will never be able to remove it entirely- only to attenuate it to some value. Anything you add will also contribute some noise itself. See EMF's answer for how to calculate the capacitance if you're just slapping a capacitor across the output, and select his answer if it's what you're looking for.

Please get into the habit of specifying **how** you are measuring the ripple and what it looks like in the frequency domain. 100mV RMS of spikey SMPS noise might easily be 1Vp-p.

Answer (score 1):

If your power supply is topped out at 12V under load and the ripple pulls it down even farther, you'll never be able to get a clean supply and the best you'll be able to do by adding capacitance across the load is to decrease the amplitude of the ripple.

The formula relating ripple voltage and capacitance is:

```
    C = It/V
```

where C is the capacitance in farads, I is the load current in amperes, t is the period of the ripple frequency in seconds, and V is the desired amplitude of the ripple voltage, in volts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate this capacitor from the voltage alone, this depends on the load. With simple rectifier, the voltage drops to zero 100 (or 120) times per second; at these moments the device is fed by the capacitor alone. The voltage always drops at these moments, but if the capacitance is sufficient, the ripple stays in tolerable boundaries. More advanced voltage converter will use a higher, generated frequency, requiring smaller transformer and smaller capacitor.

If the ripple amplitude is much smaller than the voltage, we can assume that the load consumes the constant current I. Then if V is the acceptable amplitude of the ripple, and t is the approximate duration of "no power" phase, the required capacity is equal to `I*t/V`.

This is rather approximate because the shape of the rectified current is not rectangle, however may give an idea which capacitor it could probably be. It is generally enough to take about 70 % of the calculated capacity.

You can read more about solution of this problem [here](http://www.electroschematics.com/7048/capacitor-input-filter-calculation/).

However your power supply should already have the adequate capacitor. If you observe unacceptable ripple, you are probably overloading it, and it will not serve for long anyway. Check if it is rated for the current you need.

Comment: This seems to be assuming the device is using a mains AC transformer, and a bridge rectifier.

Comment: No, it is true for any regular ripple you attempt to fix with the attached external capacitor. For the mains AC with bridge rectifier, it is a 100 (or 120) Hz ripple, and relatively large capacitor is required (large t). Much less capacitance is needed if it is a high frequency ripple (small t).

Comment: I guess I'm reading too much into `With simple rectifier, the voltage drops to zero 100 (or 120) times per second`

Comment: Added explaining sentence.